# Unmet dependencies upgrading to stretch

Tags: debian, upgrade, dist-upgrade

I just tried to upgrade my system from Debian Jessie to stretch.
First I changed `/etc/apt/sources.list` to:

```
deb http://security.debian.org/ stretch/updates main 
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ stretch/updates main

deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ stretch main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ stretch main contrib non-free
```

Then I ran `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade && apt-get dist-upgrade`. Now I have a big mess with unmet dependencies:

```
a@b ~ % sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 aptitude : Depends: libsigc++-2.0-0c2a (>= 2.2.0) but it is not installable
 calibre-bin : Depends: libicu57 (>= 57.1-1~) but it is not installed
               Recommends: calibre (>= 2.75.1+dfsg-1) but 2.5.0+dfsg-1 is installed
 djvulibre-bin : Depends: libdjvulibre21 (= 3.5.25.4-4+b1) but 3.5.27.1-7 is installed
 easytag : Depends: libtag1c2a (>= 1.9.1) but it is not installable
 evolution : Depends: evolution-data-server (< 3.13) but 3.22.7-1 is installed
 evolution-data-server : Depends: libebook-1.2-16 (>= 3.17) but it is not installed
                         Depends: libebook-contacts-1.2-2 (>= 3.16.2) but it is not installed
                         Depends: libedataserver-1.2-22 (>= 3.21.92) but it is not installed
                         Depends: libicu57 (>= 57.1-1~) but it is not installed
                         Depends: evolution-data-server-common (= 3.22.7-1) but 3.12.9~git20141128.5242b0-2+deb8u3 is installed
 gedit : Depends: libgtk-3-0 (>= 3.21.4) but 3.14.5-1+deb8u1 is installed
 gir1.2-webkit2-4.0 : Depends: libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37 (>= 2.13.91) but it is not installed
 gnome-online-accounts : Depends: libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37 (>= 2.8.1) but it is not installed
 gnome-online-miners : Depends: grilo-plugins-0.3 but it is not installed
 gnome-system-monitor : Depends: libsigc++-2.0-0c2a (>= 2.2.0) but it is not installable
 gparted : Depends: libsigc++-2.0-0c2a (>= 2.2.0) but it is not installable
 gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad : Depends: libgtk-3-0 (>= 3.16.2) but 3.14.5-1+deb8u1 is installed
 gvfs : Depends: gvfs-daemons (< 1.22.2-1.1~)
        Depends: gvfs-libs (= 1.22.2-1) but 1.30.4-1 is installed
        Depends: gvfs-common (= 1.22.2-1) but 1.30.4-1 is installed
 gvfs-backends : Depends: libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.49.3) but 2.48.0-1~bpo8+1 is installed
                 Depends: gvfs (= 1.30.4-1) but 1.22.2-1 is installed
 gvfs-bin : Depends: libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.49.3) but 2.48.0-1~bpo8+1 is installed
 gvfs-daemons : Depends: libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.49.3) but 2.48.0-1~bpo8+1 is installed
 gvfs-libs : Depends: libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.49.3) but 2.48.0-1~bpo8+1 is installed
 imagescan : Depends: libsigc++-2.0-0c2a (>= 2.2.0) but it is not installable
 inkscape : Depends: libsigc++-2.0-0c2a (>= 2.2.0) but it is not installable
 libatkmm-1.6-1 : Depends: libsigc++-2.0-0c2a (>= 2.2.0) but it is not installable
 libavfilter5 : Depends: libopencv-core2.4 but it is not installable
                Depends: libopencv-imgproc2.4 but it is not installable
 libboost-date-time1.55-dev : Depends: libboost-date-time1.55.0 (= 1.55.0+dfsg-3) but it is not installable
 libcairomm-1.0-1 : Depends: libsigc++-2.0-0c2a (>= 2.2.0) but it is not installable
 libcamel-1.2-59 : Depends: libicu57 (>= 57.1-1~) but it is not installed
 libclutter-1.0-0 : Depends: libgtk-3-0 (>= 3.16.2) but 3.14.5-1+deb8u1 is installed
 libclutter-gtk-1.0-0 : Depends: libgtk-3-0 (>= 3.21.0) but 3.14.5-1+deb8u1 is installed
 libcmis-0.4-4 : Depends: libboost-date-time1.55.0 but it is not installable
 libcpan-meta-perl : Depends: perl (>= 5.21.5) but 5.20.2-3+deb8u7 is installed or
                              libjson-pp-perl (>= 2.27300)
 libcwidget3 : Depends: libsigc++-2.0-0c2a (>= 2.2.0) but it is not installable
 libebackend-1.2-10 : Depends: libedataserver-1.2-22 (>= 3.21.90) but it is not installed
 libecal-1.2-19 : Depends: libedataserver-1.2-22 (>= 3.17) but it is not installed
 libedata-book-1.2-25 : Depends: libebook-contacts-1.2-2 (>= 3.16.2) but it is not installed
                        Depends: libedataserver-1.2-22 (>= 3.21.90) but it is not installed
 libedata-cal-1.2-28 : Depends: libedataserver-1.2-22 (>= 3.21.90) but it is not installed
 libfarstream-0.1-0 : Depends: gstreamer0.10-plugins-good (>= 0.10.29) but it is not installable
 libgdal1h : Depends: libdapserver7 but it is not installable
 libgirepository-1.0-1 : Depends: libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.50.0) but 2.48.0-1~bpo8+1 is installed
 libglibmm-2.4-1c2a : Depends: libsigc++-2.0-0c2a (>= 2.2.0) but it is not installable
 libgoa-backend-1.0-1 : Depends: libgtk-3-0 (>= 3.19.12) but 3.14.5-1+deb8u1 is installed
                        Depends: libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37 (>= 2.8.1) but it is not installed
 libgtkmm-2.4-1c2a : Depends: libsigc++-2.0-0c2a (>= 2.2.0) but it is not installable
 libgtkmm-3.0-1 : Depends: libsigc++-2.0-0c2a (>= 2.2.0) but it is not installable
 libgtksourceview-3.0-1 : Depends: libgtk-3-0 (>= 3.19.12) but 3.14.5-1+deb8u1 is installed
 libical2 : Depends: libicu57 (>= 57.1-1~) but it is not installed
 libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18 : Depends: libicu57 (>= 57.1-1~) but it is not installed
 libnautilus-extension1a : Depends: libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.49.1) but 2.48.0-1~bpo8+1 is installed
 libopenmpi-dev : Depends: libopenmpi1.6 (= 1.6.5-9.1+deb8u1) but it is not installable
 libpangomm-1.4-1 : Depends: libsigc++-2.0-0c2a (>= 2.2.0) but it is not installable
 libphonenumber6 : Depends: libboost-date-time1.55.0 but it is not installable
 libqt5core5a : Depends: libicu57 (>= 57.1-1~) but it is not installed
 libqt5webkit5 : Depends: libicu57 (>= 57.1-1~) but it is not installed
 libreoffice-calc : Depends: libicu57 (>= 57.1-1~) but it is not installed
 libreoffice-core : Depends: libicu57 (>= 57.1-1~) but it is not installed
 libreoffice-draw : Depends: libicu57 (>= 57.1-1~) but it is not installed
 libreoffice-evolution : Depends: libebook-1.2-16 but it is not installed
 libreoffice-gtk2 : Depends: libicu57 (>= 57.1-1~) but it is not installed
 libreoffice-writer : Depends: libicu57 (>= 57.1-1~) but it is not installed
 librhythmbox-core10 : Depends: libgtk-3-0 (>= 3.16.2) but 3.14.5-1+deb8u1 is installed
 libscotch-5.1 : Depends: libopenmpi1.6 but it is not installable
 libsoprano4 : Depends: libclucene-core1 (>= 2.3.3.4) but it is not installable
 libtag1v5-vanilla : Depends: libicu57 (>= 57.1-1~) but it is not installed
 libtotem0 : Depends: libgnome-desktop-3-12 (>= 3.17.92) but it is not installed
             Depends: libgtk-3-0 (>= 3.19.4) but 3.14.5-1+deb8u1 is installed
 libvtk5.8 : Depends: libopenmpi1.6 but it is not installable
 libvtk6.1 : Depends: libopenmpi1.6 but it is not installable
 libxml++2.6-2 : Depends: libsigc++-2.0-0c2a (>= 2.2.0) but it is not installable
 lightspark-common : Depends: libsigc++-2.0-0c2a (>= 2.2.0) but it is not installable
 open-vm-tools-desktop : Depends: libsigc++-2.0-0c2a (>= 2.2.0) but it is not installable
 openmpi-bin : Depends: libopenmpi1.6 but it is not installable
 paraview : Depends: libopenmpi1.6 but it is not installable
 pavucontrol : Depends: libsigc++-2.0-0c2a (>= 2.2.0) but it is not installable
 perl-doc : Depends: perl (>= 5.24.1-1) but 5.20.2-3+deb8u7 is installed
 python-vtk6 : Depends: libopenmpi1.6 but it is not installable
 python3 : Depends: python3-minimal (= 3.4.2-2) but 3.5.3-1 is installed
           Depends: libpython3-stdlib (= 3.4.2-2) but 3.5.3-1 is installed
 python3-apt : Depends: python3 (>= 3.5~) but 3.4.2-2 is installed
 python3-brlapi : Depends: python3 (>= 3.5~) but 3.4.2-2 is installed
 python3-cairo : Depends: python3 (>= 3.5~) but 3.4.2-2 is installed
 python3-dbus : Depends: python3 (>= 3.5~) but 3.4.2-2 is installed
 python3-dev : Depends: python3 (= 3.5.3-1) but 3.4.2-2 is installed
 python3-gi-cairo : Depends: python3 (>= 3.5~) but 3.4.2-2 is installed
                    Depends: python3-gi (= 3.22.0-2) but 3.14.0-1 is installed
 python3-markupsafe : Depends: python3 (>= 3.5~) but 3.4.2-2 is installed
 python3-pil : Depends: python3 (>= 3.5~) but 3.4.2-2 is installed
 python3-pyqt5 : Depends: python3 (>= 3.5~) but 3.4.2-2 is installed
 python3-pyqt5.qtwebkit : Depends: python3 (>= 3.5~) but 3.4.2-2 is installed
 python3-sip : Depends: python3 (>= 3.5~) but 3.4.2-2 is installed
 python3-uno : Depends: python3 (>= 3.5~) but 3.4.2-2 is installed
 python3-yaml : Depends: python3 (>= 3.5~) but 3.4.2-2 is installed
 rhythmbox : Depends: rhythmbox-data (= 3.1-1) but 3.4.1-2 is installed
 rhythmbox-plugins : Depends: python3 (>= 3.5~) but 3.4.2-2 is installed
                     Depends: rhythmbox (= 3.4.1-2+b1) but 3.1-1 is installed
 spamassassin : Depends: libmail-dkim-perl but it is not installed
 texlive-binaries : Depends: libptexenc1 (< 2014.20140926.35254-6.1~) but 2016.20160513.41080.dfsg-2 is installed
                    Depends: libkpathsea6 (< 2014.20140926.35254-6.1~) but 2016.20160513.41080.dfsg-2 is installed
 totem : Depends: libtotem0 (< 3.15) but 3.22.1-1 is installed
         Depends: totem-common (= 3.14.0-2) but 3.22.1-1 is installed
 totem-plugins : Depends: libgtk-3-0 (>= 3.19.4) but 3.14.5-1+deb8u1 is installed
                 Depends: totem (= 3.22.1-1) but 3.14.0-2 is installed
 vlc-nox : Depends: libtag1c2a (>= 1.9.1) but it is not installable
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

If I run `apt --fix-broken install` the problem persists:

```
a@b ~ % sudo apt --fix-broken install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... failed.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 aptitude : Depends: libsigc++-2.0-0c2a (>= 2.2.0) but it is not installable
 calibre-bin : Depends: libicu57 (>= 57.1-1~) but it is not installed
               Recommends: calibre (>= 2.75.1+dfsg-1) but 2.5.0+dfsg-1 is installed

 [The same as in the upper error log]

 totem : Depends: libtotem0 (< 3.15) but 3.22.1-1 is installed
         Depends: totem-common (= 3.14.0-2) but 3.22.1-1 is installed
 totem-plugins : Depends: libgtk-3-0 (>= 3.19.4) but 3.14.5-1+deb8u1 is installed
                 Depends: totem (= 3.22.1-1) but 3.14.0-2 is installed
 vlc-nox : Depends: libtag1c2a (>= 1.9.1) but it is not installable
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies
```

The output of `apt-get dist-upgrade`:

```
a@b ~ % sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 aptitude : Depends: libsigc++-2.0-0c2a (>= 2.2.0) but it is not installable
 calibre-bin : Depends: libicu57 (>= 57.1-1~) but it is not installed
               Recommends: calibre (>= 2.75.1+dfsg-1) but 2.5.0+dfsg-1 is installed
 djvulibre-bin : Depends: libdjvulibre21 (= 3.5.25.4-4+b1) but 3.5.27.1-7 is installed
 easytag : Depends: libtag1c2a (>= 1.9.1) but it is not installable
 evolution : Depends: evolution-data-server (< 3.13) but 3.22.7-1 is installed
 evolution-data-server : Depends: libebook-1.2-16 (>= 3.17) but it is not installed
                         Depends: libebook-contacts-1.2-2 (>= 3.16.2) but it is not installed
                         Depends: libedataserver-1.2-22 (>= 3.21.92) but it is not installed
                         Depends: libicu57 (>= 57.1-1~) but it is not installed
                         Depends: evolution-data-server-common (= 3.22.7-1) but 3.12.9~git20141128.5242b0-2+deb8u3 is installed
 gedit : Depends: libgtk-3-0 (>= 3.21.4) but 3.14.5-1+deb8u1 is installed
 gir1.2-webkit2-4.0 : Depends: libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37 (>= 2.13.91) but it is not installed
 gnome-online-accounts : Depends: libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37 (>= 2.8.1) but it is not installed
 gnome-online-miners : Depends: grilo-plugins-0.3 but it is not installed
 gnome-system-monitor : Depends: libsigc++-2.0-0c2a (>= 2.2.0) but it is not installable
 gparted : Depends: libsigc++-2.0-0c2a (>= 2.2.0) but it is not installable
 gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad : Depends: libgtk-3-0 (>= 3.16.2) but 3.14.5-1+deb8u1 is installed
 gvfs : Depends: gvfs-daemons (< 1.22.2-1.1~)
        Depends: gvfs-libs (= 1.22.2-1) but 1.30.4-1 is installed
        Depends: gvfs-common (= 1.22.2-1) but 1.30.4-1 is installed
 gvfs-backends : Depends: libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.49.3) but 2.48.0-1~bpo8+1 is installed
                 Depends: gvfs (= 1.30.4-1) but 1.22.2-1 is installed
 gvfs-bin : Depends: libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.49.3) but 2.48.0-1~bpo8+1 is installed
 gvfs-daemons : Depends: libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.49.3) but 2.48.0-1~bpo8+1 is installed
 gvfs-libs : Depends: libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.49.3) but 2.48.0-1~bpo8+1 is installed
 imagescan : Depends: libsigc++-2.0-0c2a (>= 2.2.0) but it is not installable
 inkscape : Depends: libsigc++-2.0-0c2a (>= 2.2.0) but it is not installable
 libatkmm-1.6-1 : Depends: libsigc++-2.0-0c2a (>= 2.2.0) but it is not installable
 libavfilter5 : Depends: libopencv-core2.4 but it is not installable
                Depends: libopencv-imgproc2.4 but it is not installable
 libboost-date-time1.55-dev : Depends: libboost-date-time1.55.0 (= 1.55.0+dfsg-3) but it is not installable
 libcairomm-1.0-1 : Depends: libsigc++-2.0-0c2a (>= 2.2.0) but it is not installable
 libcamel-1.2-59 : Depends: libicu57 (>= 57.1-1~) but it is not installed
 libclutter-1.0-0 : Depends: libgtk-3-0 (>= 3.16.2) but 3.14.5-1+deb8u1 is installed
 libclutter-gtk-1.0-0 : Depends: libgtk-3-0 (>= 3.21.0) but 3.14.5-1+deb8u1 is installed
 libcmis-0.4-4 : Depends: libboost-date-time1.55.0 but it is not installable
 libcpan-meta-perl : Depends: perl (>= 5.21.5) but 5.20.2-3+deb8u7 is installed or
                              libjson-pp-perl (>= 2.27300)
 libcwidget3 : Depends: libsigc++-2.0-0c2a (>= 2.2.0) but it is not installable
 libebackend-1.2-10 : Depends: libedataserver-1.2-22 (>= 3.21.90) but it is not installed
 libecal-1.2-19 : Depends: libedataserver-1.2-22 (>= 3.17) but it is not installed
 libedata-book-1.2-25 : Depends: libebook-contacts-1.2-2 (>= 3.16.2) but it is not installed
                        Depends: libedataserver-1.2-22 (>= 3.21.90) but it is not installed
 libedata-cal-1.2-28 : Depends: libedataserver-1.2-22 (>= 3.21.90) but it is not installed
 libfarstream-0.1-0 : Depends: gstreamer0.10-plugins-good (>= 0.10.29) but it is not installable
 libgdal1h : Depends: libdapserver7 but it is not installable
 libgirepository-1.0-1 : Depends: libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.50.0) but 2.48.0-1~bpo8+1 is installed
 libglibmm-2.4-1c2a : Depends: libsigc++-2.0-0c2a (>= 2.2.0) but it is not installable
 libgoa-backend-1.0-1 : Depends: libgtk-3-0 (>= 3.19.12) but 3.14.5-1+deb8u1 is installed
                        Depends: libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37 (>= 2.8.1) but it is not installed
 libgtkmm-2.4-1c2a : Depends: libsigc++-2.0-0c2a (>= 2.2.0) but it is not installable
 libgtkmm-3.0-1 : Depends: libsigc++-2.0-0c2a (>= 2.2.0) but it is not installable
 libgtksourceview-3.0-1 : Depends: libgtk-3-0 (>= 3.19.12) but 3.14.5-1+deb8u1 is installed
 libical2 : Depends: libicu57 (>= 57.1-1~) but it is not installed
 libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18 : Depends: libicu57 (>= 57.1-1~) but it is not installed
 libnautilus-extension1a : Depends: libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.49.1) but 2.48.0-1~bpo8+1 is installed
 libopenmpi-dev : Depends: libopenmpi1.6 (= 1.6.5-9.1+deb8u1) but it is not installable
 libpangomm-1.4-1 : Depends: libsigc++-2.0-0c2a (>= 2.2.0) but it is not installable
 libphonenumber6 : Depends: libboost-date-time1.55.0 but it is not installable
 libqt5core5a : Depends: libicu57 (>= 57.1-1~) but it is not installed
 libqt5webkit5 : Depends: libicu57 (>= 57.1-1~) but it is not installed
 libreoffice-calc : Depends: libicu57 (>= 57.1-1~) but it is not installed
 libreoffice-core : Depends: libicu57 (>= 57.1-1~) but it is not installed
 libreoffice-draw : Depends: libicu57 (>= 57.1-1~) but it is not installed
 libreoffice-evolution : Depends: libebook-1.2-16 but it is not installed
 libreoffice-gtk2 : Depends: libicu57 (>= 57.1-1~) but it is not installed
 libreoffice-writer : Depends: libicu57 (>= 57.1-1~) but it is not installed
 librhythmbox-core10 : Depends: libgtk-3-0 (>= 3.16.2) but 3.14.5-1+deb8u1 is installed
 libscotch-5.1 : Depends: libopenmpi1.6 but it is not installable
 libsoprano4 : Depends: libclucene-core1 (>= 2.3.3.4) but it is not installable
 libtag1v5-vanilla : Depends: libicu57 (>= 57.1-1~) but it is not installed
 libtotem0 : Depends: libgnome-desktop-3-12 (>= 3.17.92) but it is not installed
             Depends: libgtk-3-0 (>= 3.19.4) but 3.14.5-1+deb8u1 is installed
 libvtk5.8 : Depends: libopenmpi1.6 but it is not installable
 libvtk6.1 : Depends: libopenmpi1.6 but it is not installable
 libxml++2.6-2 : Depends: libsigc++-2.0-0c2a (>= 2.2.0) but it is not installable
 lightspark-common : Depends: libsigc++-2.0-0c2a (>= 2.2.0) but it is not installable
 open-vm-tools-desktop : Depends: libsigc++-2.0-0c2a (>= 2.2.0) but it is not installable
 openmpi-bin : Depends: libopenmpi1.6 but it is not installable
 paraview : Depends: libopenmpi1.6 but it is not installable
 pavucontrol : Depends: libsigc++-2.0-0c2a (>= 2.2.0) but it is not installable
 perl-doc : Depends: perl (>= 5.24.1-1) but 5.20.2-3+deb8u7 is installed
 python-vtk6 : Depends: libopenmpi1.6 but it is not installable
 python3 : Depends: python3-minimal (= 3.4.2-2) but 3.5.3-1 is installed
           Depends: libpython3-stdlib (= 3.4.2-2) but 3.5.3-1 is installed
 python3-apt : Depends: python3 (>= 3.5~) but 3.4.2-2 is installed
 python3-brlapi : Depends: python3 (>= 3.5~) but 3.4.2-2 is installed
 python3-cairo : Depends: python3 (>= 3.5~) but 3.4.2-2 is installed
 python3-dbus : Depends: python3 (>= 3.5~) but 3.4.2-2 is installed
 python3-dev : Depends: python3 (= 3.5.3-1) but 3.4.2-2 is installed
 python3-gi-cairo : Depends: python3 (>= 3.5~) but 3.4.2-2 is installed
                    Depends: python3-gi (= 3.22.0-2) but 3.14.0-1 is installed
 python3-markupsafe : Depends: python3 (>= 3.5~) but 3.4.2-2 is installed
 python3-pil : Depends: python3 (>= 3.5~) but 3.4.2-2 is installed
 python3-pyqt5 : Depends: python3 (>= 3.5~) but 3.4.2-2 is installed
 python3-pyqt5.qtwebkit : Depends: python3 (>= 3.5~) but 3.4.2-2 is installed
 python3-sip : Depends: python3 (>= 3.5~) but 3.4.2-2 is installed
 python3-uno : Depends: python3 (>= 3.5~) but 3.4.2-2 is installed
 python3-yaml : Depends: python3 (>= 3.5~) but 3.4.2-2 is installed
 rhythmbox : Depends: rhythmbox-data (= 3.1-1) but 3.4.1-2 is installed
 rhythmbox-plugins : Depends: python3 (>= 3.5~) but 3.4.2-2 is installed
                     Depends: rhythmbox (= 3.4.1-2+b1) but 3.1-1 is installed
 spamassassin : Depends: libmail-dkim-perl but it is not installed
 texlive-binaries : Depends: libptexenc1 (< 2014.20140926.35254-6.1~) but 2016.20160513.41080.dfsg-2 is installed
                    Depends: libkpathsea6 (< 2014.20140926.35254-6.1~) but 2016.20160513.41080.dfsg-2 is installed
 totem : Depends: libtotem0 (< 3.15) but 3.22.1-1 is installed
         Depends: totem-common (= 3.14.0-2) but 3.22.1-1 is installed
 totem-plugins : Depends: libgtk-3-0 (>= 3.19.4) but 3.14.5-1+deb8u1 is installed
                 Depends: totem (= 3.22.1-1) but 3.14.0-2 is installed
 vlc-nox : Depends: libtag1c2a (>= 1.9.1) but it is not installable
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

What's the way to go to fix it?

Comment: Please check for held packages as described in the [release notes](https://www.debian.org/releases/testing/amd64/release-notes/ch-upgrading.en.html#system-status). The misplaced line break in your `sources.list` is a typo, right?

Comment: @FerencWágner No, the newline between the two `security.*` and `ftp.*` lines is there. When I click on your "release notes" link I get a 403 Forbidden error. Do you have another link?

Comment: @FerencWágner Ah, now I see what you mean with misplaced line break. Yes, it was a typo in the question. I've fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I traced the problem back to a manual installation of `python3.5`.

After manually removing it (`rm -r /usr/local/python*`) as described in [this bug](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=852163), the dist-upgrade worked out well.

Comment: Any suggestion how someone with this problem could trace the problem back to python (or not)? The linked bug has a nice error message for this, but it doesn't show up in the question here.